# Can I install IE 7 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-7

Can I install IE7 in Windows 7?

I want to replace IE8 and need to install IE7 in my Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all the overhead installing your own IE in Windows 7 XP Mode I would use the [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) with [Windows 7 Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) which is now available for 32bit versions as well. You can choose "Don’t need XP Mode and want VPC only? Download Windows Virtual PC without Windows XP Mode." if you don't want to download XP Mode at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as well as IE6: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ie6-ie7-ie8-win7-xp-mode

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it by normal way, but you can try that:

Run IE6 IE7 IE8 at Same Time - Internet Explorer Collection
http://softzilla.blogspot.com/2009/03/run-ie6-ie7-ie8-at-same-time-internet.html

Answer (score 0):

why you want to install ie7? if you want to install it to test website then you can install ietester. here is the link
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 0):

I find that for most purposes, it is sufficient to put IE8 into IE7 render mode.

F12 (Tools | Developer Tools) -> Browser Mode | Internet Explorer 7, Document Mode | IE7 Standards Alt+7.

I believe the "Browser Mode" is actually just changing the user agent string. The "Document Mode" actually enables the IE7 trident rendering engine. Unfortunately, you still get the IE8 javascript engine.