# Selectively use Internet Explorer 7 alongside machine with IE9 installed

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7

I have Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 9. I am a government employee needing to access my travel department from my personal computer. Security protocol indicates I must use Internet Explorer 7 or earlier to access and that Internet Explorer 9 doesn't meet security certificate requirements.

Can I install Internet Explorer 7 and select it for use when needed?

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer 7 is not available on Windows 7 without some major shoehorning. Windows 7 ships with Internet Explorer 8. In order to use Internet Explorer 7 or below, you should use a virtual machine with Windows XP installed. Take a look at the [Virtual PC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) from Microsoft, or try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried accessing the site and IE8 is the latest supported version.

This is the message that I received when trying to access the site. So it makes it much easier to use both IE8 and IE9 on Windows 7 than going all the way down to IE7 and having a much tougher time doing so.

```
We support the following browsers and versions.

Internet Explorer 6.0
Internet Explorer 7.0
Internet Explorer 8.0
Firefox 3.0
Firefox 3.5
Firefox 3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

Run IE6 IE7 IE8 at Same Time - Internet Explorer Collection http://softzilla.blogspot.com/2009/03/run-ie6-ie7-ie8-at-same-time-internet.html

(that question is like yours: [Can I install IE 7 on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/218926/can-i-install-ie-7-on-windows-7/218952#218952))